# What might prevent a Yongnuo MC-36R remote controller from triggering a Canon 7D wirelessly?

Tags: remote, wireless-triggers, shutter-release, wireless

I have purchased a Yongnuo MC-36R  - both hand held remote and camera fitted receiver will fire the Canon 7D by cable, but the wireless remote will not work.  I have both sets of dip switches set to ON but all other combinations I have tried also don't work.

I returned the first one they sent me and they replaced it with an identical model, but it too has the same problem.  Makes me think I am doing something wrong.

Anyone had this problem or could suggest an answer.

Comment: Silly question, but somebody's gotta ask it: have you checked that the batteries are fresh and properly installed?

Comment: Changed battery in receiver and now works OK - should have checked that first.

Answer (score 2):

Dead batteries would. :) (Making it an answer, since it apparently *was* the answer.)